# Redundant lines in disassembly file generated by arm-none-eabi toolchain

Tags: disassembly, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I'm working on an embedded program for an ARM Cortex-M0 microcontroller using the arm-none-eabi toolchain and standard GNU make. I'm noticing some redundant .word lines in the disassembly output, and I'm wondering if there's a way to get rid of them.

This is the version of the toolchain:

> (Arm GNU Toolchain 12.2.MPACBTI-Rel1 (Build arm-12-mpacbti.34)) 12.2.1
> 20230214

Here's an example of the disassembly output (note this is only part of the file):

```
080000de <fillZeroBss>:
fillZeroBss():
 80000de:   6008        str r0, [r1, #0]
 80000e0:   3104        adds    r1, #4

080000e2 <loopFillZeroBss>:
loopFillZeroBss():
 80000e2:   4291        cmp r1, r2
 80000e4:   d3fb        bcc.n   80000de <fillZeroBss>
 80000e6:   f000 f80c   bl  8000102 <main>
 80000ea:   0000        .short  0x0000
 80000ec:   20000000    .word   0x20000000
 80000f0:   20000000    .word   0x20000000
 80000f4:   08000104    .word   0x08000104
 80000f8:   20000000    .word   0x20000000
 80000fc:   20000000    .word   0x20000000

08000100 <defaultHandler>:
defaultHandler():
 8000100:   e7fe        b.n 8000100 <defaultHandler>

08000102 <main>:
main():
/home/matej/usb_test/src/main.cpp:3 (discriminator 1)
int main()
{
    while(true);
 8000102:   e7fe        b.n 8000102 <main>
```

I mean the lines between

```
80000e6:   f000 f80c   bl  8000102 <main>
```

and

```
08000100 <defaultHandler>:
```

Are they some kind of a guard for a case if main function would return?